# Add Realtime Database SDK to your App button didn,t work .how to fix it

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQdpA.png)

this button doent work,i hit that 100 times but,didn,t addsdk to app

i tried to add it manually but it also didn,t work...

Comment: "I tried to add it manually but it also didn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly didn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.